# Opencv Masking via grayscale img does not work

Tags: python, opencv, masking

I am a newbe in Opencv. When I use inverse of gray scale image for masking it works but gray scale does not work. What do I miss ? What does mask actually do? I want to use gray img to mask real img.

```
img1 = cv2.imread('cv_python/DATA/watermark_no_copy.png')
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(img1)
```

[image]

```
img1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
plt.imshow(img1_gray, cmap = 'gray')
```

[image]

```
img1_g_inv = 255 - img1_gray
my_background = np.full(img1.shape, (255, 255, 255), dtype = np.uint8)
plt.imshow(my_background)
```

[image]

```
my_mask = cv2.bitwise_and(my_background, my_background, mask = img1_gray)
plt.imshow(my_mask)
```

[image]

```
my_mask2 = cv2.bitwise_and(my_background, my_background, mask = img1_g_inv)
plt.imshow(my_mask2)
```

[image]

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: black writings on the white background like gray scale one but I can not achieve that through masking

Comment: @slaihgg did you figure this out?

Comment: No, actually i did not strive with this too much.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change `my_background` and `my_mask` like

**before**

```
my_background = np.full(img1.shape, (255, 255, 255), dtype = np.uint8)
my_mask = cv2.bitwise_and(my_background, my_background, mask = img1_gray)
```

**after**

```
my_background = np.full(img1_gray.shape, 255, dtype = np.uint8)
my_mask = cv2.bitwise_and(img1_gray, img1_gray, mask = my_background)
```

Comment: when I do this, my_mask is being gray img not an RGB

Comment: If you want to RGB mask, why do you use gray image in bitwise operator ?

Comment: That function returns me an RGB img just mask is uint8 grayscale img, if I can achieve RGB img using gray_scale img, I will use it in bitwise afterwards